# Does qemu/kvm support ovf?

Tags: qemu, kvm

Does qemu/kvm support ovf?
Is it able to boot existing ovf packages?
I can not find any related info both in ovf standard and qemu/kvm website.
Any helpful link on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are looking for [virt-tools](http://virt-tools.org/) which contains `virt-convert` which is intended to be used to convert OVF to a format usable to QEMU.  It would probably help to build from the latest source.  The git repo is now https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager

Answer (score 1):

`virt-convert` is not part of newer versions of `virt-tools` anymore. An alternative called `virt-v2v` was developed as a part of `libguestfs`. You might still get this tool in some older versions of `libguestfs`, but it was split to a separate project: https://github.com/libguestfs/virt-v2v. As of writing I haven't found `virt-v2v` in any package repos yet. So the straight forward way to get it is building it from source.